# Excel alphabetize column gathered from different column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with the projects in column `A` and the date of that project in column `B`:

[image]

I would like to those two columns placed in column `D` and `E`, respectively, and as I add them in column `A` & `B`, have them be placed alphabetically in column `D` & `E`.

Comment: The formula outlined on this page should do the trick:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rank.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first cell of the column "Proposed project", paste this formula:

```
=INDEX(projects,COUNTIF(projects, "<"&A2)+SUM(IF(A2=$A$2:A2, 1, 0)))
```

with `A2` pointing the first cell in the "Proposed project" column.

In the first cell of the column "Date submitted", paste this formula:

```
=INDEX(Dates,MATCH(D2,projects,0))
```

with `D2` pointing the cell where you just pasted the formula above.

Then drag them both to the end of your data.

Notes:

1. The range `projects` is the column with all the existing project names (without the title)
2. The range `Dates` is the column with all the existing dates of the projects (without the title)

   [image: Sorting columns]